# fuel consumption and high ravs

Tags: toyota, fuel-consumption

I changed the sub assembly for my toyota altezza but now its consuming too much fuel and now the rav count will at 2000rpm at low speeds 20-60km/h, it had an engine check light for knock sensor and vvti sensor. so l repositioned the vvti sensor and replaced one knock sensor but its still giving me the same problem..help pliz

Comment: Sounds like maybe your transmission isn't shifting into the top gear.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What "sub assembly" did you replace?